# How to get meeting details in Microsoft Teams from javascript sdk or graph sdk?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams

I'm try to develop a Custom Tab for Meetings in Microsoft Teams. I could not obtain any details on the teams meeting.

The Context object has a `meetingId` but I can't get any OnlineMeeting or Event details when requesting via the Graph API.

Also, if we are in a series of meetings, then the `meetingId` is the same for all occurrences.

So, how can I retrieve meeting details (name, scheduled date and time, participants, etc.) from within a Custom Tab in a Teams meeting?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently **not supported** to get the meeting details in meting-tab functionality.

Comment: Can you provide a link to any source for where it's not supported?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/create-apps-for-teams-meetings?tabs=dotnet#before-a-meeting
Currently, in meetings tab, getting meeting details and participant information is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

As this feature is not available at present, could you please raise an [User Voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's possible at least there is a [sample "My First Meeting App" in teams toolkit](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v1.1.0/hello-world-in-meeting) that is retrieving the meeting Id using Javascript SDK.
Now, I'm trying to get the meeting Id using Graph SDK :)

```
class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      context: {}
    }
  }

  //React lifecycle method that gets called once a component has finished mounting
  //Learn more: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount
  componentDidMount(){
    app.initialize().then(() => {
      // Get the user context from Teams and set it in the state
      app.getContext().then(async (context) => {
        this.setState({
          meetingId: context.meeting.id,
          userName: context.user.userPrincipalName
        });
      });
    });
    // Next steps: Error handling using the error object
  }
```